# SKPSMTPMessage setWatchdogTimer:]: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, email, smtp

i have used `SKPSSMTP` for send email in background. I have refer this [code](https://github.com/jetseven/skpsmtpmessage)  for that but i am getting `SKPSMTPMessage setWatchdogTimer:]: message sent to de allocated instance` this message in log and also email is received successfully. To resolve this i have used ARC classes from [here](http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/issues/detail?id=56) but in that case i don't receive emails. Please help.

Comment: How did you received mails ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a kind of similar issue and i solved it by making my SKPSMTPMessage instance strong property and setting it to nil after the message has been successfully sent

Comment: Thank You @Andrey Chernukha You are LIFE SAVER :)

Answer (score 2):

I solve this problem by doing some hack in `SKPSMTPMessage.h` file.

Try to change:

`@property(nonatomic, assign) id <SKPSMTPMessageDelegate> delegate;`

to:

`@property(nonatomic, strong) id <SKPSMTPMessageDelegate> delegate;`